# Trying to pass a model containing an IFormFile property from angular to asp.net core web api

Tags: javascript, sql-server, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass a model that contains about 8 properties and an IFormFile property.
When I pass the model without the file the request will be okay or otherwise, But when I add the file to the model and try to send it I get an internal server error with this description
"Error: Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile'. Path: $.corePhoto | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 173.
"

Angular 14:

component sheet:

```
userForm = this.fb.group({
    userName: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(24)]],
    email: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    phoneNumber: [''],
    passwordHash: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern('(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(  ?=.*  [$@$!#^~%*?&,.<>"\'\\;:\{\\\}\\\[\\\]\\\|\\\+\\\-\\\=\\\_\\\)\\\(\\\)\\\`\\\/\\\\\\]])[A-Za-z0-9\d$@].{7,}'), 
    Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(16)]],
    firstName: ['', [ Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(24)]],
    lastName: ['', [ Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(24)]],
    gender: [true]
  }) as FormGroup;


  userFormSubmition(files: any){

    let fileToUpload = <File>files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    this.userService.createUser(this.userForm.value).subscribe(response => {
```

service

```
  createUser(userCreation: UserCreation){
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'CreateUser', userCreation);
  }
```

Asp.net core 6 web api

Model

```
    public class ApplicationUserCreationDto : ApplicationUserDto
    {
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public IFormFile CorePhoto { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Method

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("CreateUser")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(ApplicationUserCreationDto userCreationDto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //upload photo
                var file = userCreationDto.CorePhoto;
                var folderName = Path.Combine("Resources", "Users/Images");
                var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName;
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName.ToString());
                    var dbPath = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName.ToString());
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(stream);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that you need to have both correct API definition and UI request.

1. API should look like this (notice that I've added [FromForm] attribute

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UploadController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("CreateUser")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser([FromForm]ApplicationUserCreationDto userCreationDto)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            user = userCreationDto.UserName,
            fileName = userCreationDto.Photo.FileName
        });
    }
}

public class ApplicationUserCreationDto
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
}
```

2. UI should sent a request with `Content-Type` header equal to `multipart/form-data` value, check it in network. Code probably should look like this

```
let formData = new FormData();

Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(formControlName => {
formData.append(formControlName,  this.form.get(formControlName).value);    
 });      
this.http.post('http://localhost:4200/api/trip',formData).subscribe(          
   (response) =>console.log(response),   
   (error) =>console.log(error)  
 )}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I append the controls to the FormData, and worked successfully as you said thanks.